# puzzled with ColorData

Tags: plotting, color, legending

At first let me thank, from this point as well, those that they replied to my previous queries.

From a reply I got, I obtained finally the desired graph.

```
lst = {10*Cos[u]*Sin[v], 3*Sin[u]*Sin[v], 2*Cos[v]};
dam = Sqrt[(1296*Cos[u]^4*
       Sin[v]^4)/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 36*Cos[u]^2*Sin[v]^2 + 
        400*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2)^2 + (3600*Cos[u]^2*
       Sin[v]^2*(9*Cos[v]^2 + 4*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2))/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 
        4*(9*Cos[u]^2 + 100*Sin[u]^2)*Sin[v]^2)^2];
colFun = Function[{u, v}, Evaluate@Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]];
{min, max} = {0, 1};
ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{Hue, {min, max}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

[image]

Now, what I want is to check the outputs of other available color schemes.

I did the following:

```
coldata = ColorData["Gradients"];
col = Table[{i, coldata[[i]], ColorData[coldata[[i]]]}, {i, 51}];
```

So, for instance (for ColorData["BrightBands"])

```
{min, max} = {0, 1};
lst = {10*Cos[u]*Sin[v], 3*Sin[u]*Sin[v], 2*Cos[v]};
colFun = Function[{u, v}, Evaluate@col[[10, 3]][Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]];
h = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 800, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{colFun, {min, max}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

[image]

The coloring of the ellipsoid is as desired, but this does not hold true for the color bar.

Obviously, something I made wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You defined your function `colFun` to expect two arguments. It is not clear what you want the result to look like, therefore here are three different possible solutions:

```
ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colFun[#, #] &, {min, max}}]]
```

[image: v1]

```
ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{col[[10, 3]][#] &, {min, max}}]]
```

[image: v2]

```
ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (colFun[#4, #5] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{col[[10, 3]][#] &, {min, max}}, 20]]
```

[image: v3]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer (amazng after one year:)!). It was very helpful.